# Android music files location?

Tags: android

I'm writing a music player app and I'm wondering where should I look for the user's music files. I want to find all the songs that the Music app normally finds and I'm curious how that app finds the songs. Is there an enum variable for a specific folder? Just a recursive search of the sd card? I know on my phone's sd card there's a Music folder; is that how it is on every android device and should I just recursively search that folder? Or should I just ask the user to find the folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find all music files from sdcard using below function.

```
public void getAllSongsFromSDCARD() 
{
    String[] STAR = { "*" };        
    Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    cursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, STAR, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String song_name = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


                String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));



            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that really opens my eyes to some of the structure of the Android OS. This is such a simple app, but I'm learning so much. Thanks.

Comment: What if I only want the Music folder path?

Answer (score 2):

Android automatically scans all external SD cards for audio and indexes this data, see the [MediaStore.Audio](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html) class for details. This allows you to query by Albums, Artists, Genres and Playlists. If you just want a list of media files can be found by querying the content provider [MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).