# Android app force close on sd card audio load

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm trying to load an mp3 file which is stored on my sdcard. I'm using an HTC One phone that's why the path looks funny but i'm 90% it's correct.

Could somebody help me figure out why the app keeps force closing when I start my activity page2.java?

here's my code

```
   public class page2 extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    boolean isPlaying = false;  


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.page2);

        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/Audio/sounds/first.mp3");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
                | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         mediaPlayer.start();

        final ImageView Play_button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);


                Play_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  if(isPlaying){
                      Play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopicon);

                       isPlaying = false;

                  }else {
                      Play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);


                       isPlaying = true;
                  }
                 }
                });

    }







}
```

and this is my log

```
05-19 21:33:54.337: I/dalvikvm-heap(23333): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.389MB for 7322452-byte allocation
05-19 21:33:54.417: I/dalvikvm-heap(23333): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.376MB for 7322452-byte allocation
05-19 21:33:54.497: I/dalvikvm-heap(23333): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.365MB for 7322452-byte allocation
05-19 21:33:55.438: I/dalvikvm-heap(23333): Grow heap (frag case) to 129.877MB for 26873872-byte allocation
05-19 21:33:56.649: I/dalvikvm-heap(23333): Grow heap (frag case) to 155.560MB for 26873872-byte allocation
05-19 21:33:56.870: I/dalvikvm-heap(23333): Grow heap (frag case) to 164.561MB for 9437200-byte allocation
05-19 21:33:56.940: W/dalvikvm(23333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416a0e18)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333): Process: com.example.app, PID: 23333
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.page2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at com.example.app.page2.onCreate(page2.java:31)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
05-19 21:33:56.950: E/AndroidRuntime(23333):    ... 11 more
05-19 21:34:02.676: D/Process(23333): killProcess, pid=23333
05-19 21:34:02.676: D/Process(23333): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:131 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Comment: Because of a NPE at line `31` in `page2` activity (from Logcat: `at com.example.app.page2.onCreate(page2.java:31)`). Could you tell us what it is?

Comment: mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/Audio/sounds/first.mp3");

Comment: Are you sure the `mp3` exists.

Comment: 100% certain as I can play it from my phone

Comment: Never use hard-coded paths with Android. Even if you are right about that path it won't necessarily be right on any other device.

Comment: I know but I'm only making this app for my device

Comment: Oh, and you haven't initialized your `MediaPlayer` which is why it is null.

Comment: isn't that what "MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;" is?

Comment: No that's just a declaration.

Comment: It's just the `var` declaration. See the bellow answer, it initializes it. Use it before the `try` condition.

Comment: Could you leave an answer with it initialized in my code?

Comment: @Fllo but i'm loading the file from the sd card. I don't have anything stored in raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `var` declaration before the `try` condition as follows:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

This will create a new `MediaPlayer` retrieved by the `var` previously created.

Comment: Also, as *Squonk* mentioned, you should never hardcode paths. It is better to use `DIRECTORY_MUSIC` as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269646/2668136) mentioned and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428507/android-music-files-location) might help you, @user1300788.

Answer (score 0):

Your [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder%29) is `null`

`mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);`

[Using MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer)

Comment: where about would I add this into my code? and are you sure it's correct because my audio files aren't stored in raw

Comment: The above is the format, you can place your file anywhere and get the location of the file accordingly. Refer the example `Using MediaPlayer`.